# Does Vagrant require a separate installation of Ansible?

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I need to distribute a Vagrant file to people who already have Vagrant installed.

What I am not sure about, is whether Vagrant requires a separate installation of Ansible or whether Ansible is automatically installed together with Vagrant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible must be installed on the machine in addition to Vagrant (and likely Virtualbox).

Stealing from my own project documentation.

### Developer installation

- [Download and install Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html)
- [Download and install VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- Install Ansible

  - OSX: `brew install ansible`
  - Ubuntu (see below)

### Ansible from source for Ubuntu:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python-pip python-dev git -y
pip install PyYAML jinja2 paramiko
git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git
cd ansible
make install
```

### Notes on Vagrant plus Ansible

Snippets from the `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 4096 # we're running Java, need more than the 512mb default
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "10"] # no graphics used.
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "../provisioning/vagrant.yml"
    ansible.inventory_path = "../provisioning/hosts.ini"
    ansible.limit = "vagrant"
```

We use the following for a `vagrant-inventory.ini`:

```
[vagrant]
192.168.111.222
```

And the `vagrant.yml`:

```
- hosts: vagrant
  sudo: yes
  pre_tasks:
    (early init tasks here)
  roles:
    - role1
    - role2
```

Hope this helps.